# CodeIgniter i18n Routing Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, internationalization

I'm building a multilingual website with `CodeIgniter 3.0` version and have some errors on routing side.

First of all, I'm using [this](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n) library for i18n. Surely I made little changes for version 3.0 'cause this library is for 2.0 version. I just made that change on `MY_Config.php` file.

Original `MY_Config.php` file:

```
class MY_Config extends CI_Config {

    function site_url($uri = '')
    {   
        if (is_array($uri))
        {
            $uri = implode('/', $uri);
        }

        if (class_exists('CI_Controller'))
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $uri = $CI->lang->localized($uri);          
        }

        return parent::site_url($uri);
    }

}
```

My `MY_Config.php` file:

```
class MY_Config extends CI_Config
{
    public function site_url($uri = '', $protocol = NULL)
    {    
        if (is_array($uri))
        {
            $uri = implode('/', $uri);
        }

        if (function_exists('get_instance'))
        {
            $uri = get_instance()->lang->localized($uri);            
        }

        return parent::site_url($uri, $protocol);
    }
}
```

My problem is about `(:num)` thing. All pages are routing normally except `(:num)`'s. For example this one is working perfectly;

```
$route['^(tr|en)/(.+)$'] =  '$2';

$route['tr/admin/main'] =   'back/home';
```

But this one is not working. It gives `404 error`.

```
$route['^(tr|en)/(.+)$'] =  '$2';

$route['tr/admin/main/(:num)'] =    'back/home/$1';
```

I tried to change `back/home/$1` to `back/home/$3` but nothing changed.

I also have one more problem which I couldn't solve. If I want to use more languages, I have to add different variables of routing file in this structure. For example; if I want to use French, I need to add this line on `application/config/routes.php`:

`$route['fr/admin/main/(:num)'] =   'back/home/$1';`

But I know that is not the true method. If you have any offer for this one too, you make me happy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!

Just delete `$route['^(tr|en)/(.+)$'] =     "$2";` line on `application/config/routes.php`. That's all.

Comment: You don't need to delete it. Just switch places of those. I.E. first `$route['tr/admin/main/(:num)'] =    'back/home/$1';` than `$route['^(tr|en)/(.+)$'] =  '$2';`. Pay attention on pecedence of routes in documentation.